# Number theory problem on Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $T$ be the smallest positive integer which, when divided by $11,13,15$ leaves remainders in the sets $\{7,8,9\},\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}$ respectively. What is the sum of the squares of the digits of $T$?

My working

After applying CRT, I got

$T\equiv 469+1365a+495b+286c\,\, \left(\mod 2145\right)$
where $a,b,c\in\{0,1,2\}$

Now what to do should I check all 27 cases?

By trail and error I got $T=184,$ for $a=1,b=1,c=0$

Is this smallest?

Comment: Would it perhaps be easier if you shift $a,b,c$ to the set $\{-1,0,+1\}$, and obtain $$T\equiv 470-780a+495b+286c\pmod{2145}?$$

Comment: From the above observation, it can be established immediately that $T\leq 470$.  If $a=+1$, then $b=+1$ must hold, and so $c=0$, yielding $T=185$.  If $a=0$, then either $(b,c)=(-1,+1)$, or $(b,c)=(0,-1)$, yielding $T=261$ or $T=184$.  Finally, if $a=-1$, then $b=c=-1$, so $T=469$.  Thus, $T=184$ is indeed the smallest.  There are far fewer cases to check than $27$ if you set things up right.

Comment: Thanks sir I almost did the same yes it is indeed better to take -1,0,1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use computer support to verify. (There is nothing structural in the given setting, and it is a finite quick search.) For instance, using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: for k in [1..10000]:
....:     if k%11 in (7,8,9) and k%13 in (1,2,3) and k%15 in (4,5,6):
....:         print k
....:         break
....:     
184
```

This answer is a check. (Not a human unaided solution. But the aids do not differ much from what was needed to post the question...)

---

Later edit.
It seems that a "human other solution" is needed.
In this case the best way to get a quick answer is for me the following one. We work modulo $15$ first. The first $13$ possibilities for a match modulo $15$ are as follows, and in the contest we really write them down:

```
sage: for k in [0..12]:
....:     print "%3s %3s %3s" % ( 15*k + 4, 15*k + 5, 15*k + 6 )
....:     
  4   5   6
 19  20  21
 34  35  36
 49  50  51
 64  65  66
 79  80  81
 94  95  96
109 110 111
124 125 126
139 140 141
154 155 156
169 170 171
184 185 186
```

The computer was only helping me type the stuff. Now we further check the condition modulo $13$, which repeats in the next set/package, too. The possible numbers are than among the above:

```
sage: f = lambda k:    k if k%13 in (1,2,3) else '-'
sage: for k in [0..12]:
....:     print "%3s %3s %3s" % ( f(15*k + 4), f(15*k + 5), f(15*k + 6) )
....:     
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -  66
 79  80  81
 94   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  - 170 171
184 185   -
```

In the contest i would have underlined in the already typed columns.
This is again simple to check with bare hands, and it also gives the pattern. The above numbers match the conditions modulo $13$, and modulo $15$. The next numbers are obtained by adding $13\cdot 15$ to the above "package". Now we search in the list the first one that also matches the condition modulo $11$. If not above, then in the next package, if even not, than we add once more $13\cdot 15$.

The solution is $184$, the above numbers taken modulo $11$ are...

```
sage: f = lambda k:    k%11 if k%13 in (1,2,3) else '-'
sage: for k in [0..12]:
....:     print "%3s %3s %3s" % ( f(15*k + 4), f(15*k + 5), f(15*k + 6) )
....:     
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   0
  2   3   4
  6   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   -   -
  -   5   6
  8   9   -
```

Note: If the condition modulo $11$ would have been to hit the reminder $1$ and/or $7$, then we would have to go to the next "package" with numbers obtained from the already typed ones by adding $13\times 15$, which is $2\times 4=8$ modulo $11$, so we add $8$ to the above computed reminders 
and look for the first $1$ and/or $7$...

Comment: This problem came in Pre RMO 2018 in India. Students were supposed to solve this by pen and paper.

Comment: An excellent exercise for the good  indian students . I understand now the type of this problem.

Comment: @Makar Then please specify this information in the post. The posted question was a completely different one, namely "Is this smallest?". The answer was design to answer strictly this question. If a human answer is needed... Well, then i have to give a different answer, if any. I will also add something in the above...

Comment: ......here.....

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your specific question, *yes*. I thought that the simplest (although possibly not quickest) way to check would be to check all the consecutive triplets satisfying the condition for remainder upon division by $15$, up to $184$. For the sake of having a more complete answer, these are:

$\{19,20,21\}$,
$\{34,35,36\}$,
$\{49,50,51\}$,
$\{64,65,66\}$,
$\{79,80,81\}$,
$\{94,95,96\}$,
$\{109,110,111\}$,
$\{124,125,126\}$,
$\{139,140,141\}$,
$\{154,155,156\}$,
$\{169,170,171\}$,
$\{184,185,186\}$.

The first number that works is $184$.